# Exportar consulta no SQL Server para arquivo CSV

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, vbs

Preciso de alguma forma exportar o resultado da minha consulta SQL para um arquivo CSV. Porém, tem que ser diretamente via SQL ou VBS.

Ou então, pode ser exportado todos os dados da tabela do banco de dados para CSV.

Comment: Com o SQLServer, após realizar a consulta, vá até o resultado e clique com o botão direito do mouse:
[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e19mF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e19mF.png) A primeira opção de formado para salvar vai ser `.csv`.

Comment: O utilitário [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms162802.aspx) possibilita a exportação de dados para arquivo de texto, formato CSV. Através da opção -t é possível definir o separador de campos. Recomendo a leitura prévia do documento [Especificar terminadores de campo e linha](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms191485.aspx). Também é possível o uso da função [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190312.aspx) para exportar.

Comment: Alguns artigos sobre o assunto:

 - [Como exportar dados do banco para arquivo texto](https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/sql-server-como-exportar-dados-do-banco-para-arquivo-texto-clr-ole-bcp/)
 - [Working with the bcp Command-line Utility](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/)    
 - [SQL Server Export to Excel using bcp/sqlcmd Utilities and CSV Files](https://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-csv.htm)

Comment: Porém, precisava fazer exatamente isso através de código.

Comment: Consegui exportar do SQL Server para CSV através do código `exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "Select E3TimeStamp, Message, USUARIO, Acked, Severity, FormattedValue, Area, EventType From [c1_alarmes].[dbo].[table_alarmes]" queryout D:\bcp_outputTable.CSV -c -t; -T -S localhost\Testes'` O mesmo gerou o arquivo CVS após habilitar xp_cmdshell através do comando: `exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1` `RECONFIGURE` `EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1` `RECONFIGURE` Uma dúvida que ainda tenho, no arquivo gerado não mostra o nome de cada coluna. Se alguém souber como acrescentar isso na geração

Comment: antes de salvar você precisa fazer isso: 2. No menu “Ferramentas” > “Opções” > “Resultado da Consulta” > “SQL Server” > “Resultado em Grade” e neste campo certifique-se que a opção “Incluir cabeçalho de coluna ao copiar ou salvar os resultados” esteja selecionado, se não estiver, selecione e reinicie o SQL Server.